# Calculate a series up to five decimal places

Tags: c, floating-point

I want to write a C program that will calculate a series:

```
1/x + 1/2*x^2 + 1/3*x^3 + 1/4*x^4 + ...
```

up to five decimal places.

The program will take `x` as input and print the `f(x)` (value of series) up to five decimal places. Can you help me?

Comment: Needs appropriate language tag and probably `homework` tag too.

Answer (score 1):

For evaluating a polynomial, Horner form generally has better numerical stability than expanded form See http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5/Add-onsLinks/StandardPackages/Algebra/Horner.html

If first term was a typo then try `(((((1/4 )* x + 1/3) * x ) + 1/2) * x + 1) * x`
Else if first term is really 1/x `(((((1/4 )* x + 1/3) * x ) + 1/2) * x*x + 1/x`

Of course, you still have to analyze convergence and numerical stability as developped in Eric Postpischil answer.

Last thing, does the serie you submited as example really converge to a finite value for some x???

Answer (score 0):

In order to know that the sum you have calculated is within a desired distance to the limit of the series, you need to demonstrate that the sources of error are less than the desired distance.

When evaluating a series numerically, there are two sources of error. One is the limitations of numerical calculation, such as floating-point rounding. The other is the sum of the remaining terms, which have not been added into the partial sum.

The numerical error depends on the calculations done. For each series you want to evaluate, a custom analysis of the error must be performed. For the sample series you show, a crude but sufficient bound on the numerical error could like be calculated without too much effort. Is this the series you are primarily interested in, or are there others?

The sum of the remaining terms also requires a custom analysis. Often, given a series, we can find an expression that can be proven to be at least as large as the sum of all remaining terms but that is more easily calculated.

After you have established bounds on these two errors, you could sum terms of the series until the sum of the two bounds is less than the desired distance.